# YouTube api v3 check user max upload limit (minutes)

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube upload limit was 15 minutes but no longer.

> https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71673?hl=en

But using Youtube api to upload a video to user profile, how to check that user is not limited to 15 minutes only ?